# Go: can't receive syscall.SIGINT in for select loop

Tags: go, signals, channel

I tried to catch the interrupt signal to stop the program, but in the for-select loop, Even if the program is stopped, the default branch will continue to be entered.The code show as below:

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
    for {
        select {
        case signal := <-c:
            {
                fmt.Println("receive signal", signal)
                os.Exit(0)
            }
        default:
        }
    }
}
```

One solution is to add a buffer to c, like:

```
c := make(chan os.Signal,1)
```

But I don't know why it works.

In addition, I tried to delete the default branch and replace it with no-block branchs.And c remains without buffer

```
c := make(chan os.Signal)
signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
select {
        case signal := <- c:
            fmt.Println("receive signal", signal)
            buffer.Flush()
            os.Exit(0)
        case b := <- bodyChannel:
            w, _ := json.Marshal(b)
            buffer.Write(w)
            buffer.WriteString("\n")
        case <- t.C:
            fmt.Println("flush")
            err := buffer.Flush()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("flush err", err.Error())
            }
            t.Reset(time.Second* 1)
}
```

One of the other two branches is to continuously read data from a channel and write it to a file, and the other is to flush regularly.
In this scenario, the stop signal can be caught without the buffer. What is the difference between these two scenarios? and when buffers are needed?

Comment: Adding buffer works because `Package signal will not block sending to c: the caller must ensure that c has sufficient buffer space to keep up with the expected signal rate.` See https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal#Notify

Comment: @ain In my first code, what blocked the c receiving signal?

Comment: what the doc says (as I understand it) is that there has to be receiver ready to read when package signal attempts to send - having buffered channel guarantees that (given that the buffer is not full already). In your code without buffer you have to be really lucky that the main is at the line `case signal := <-c` at that exact moment. But most of the time it isn't...

Comment: @ain Yes, I read the source code, and as you said, unless very lucky, the signal may be missed. Thank you.

Comment: Your first loop is also a busy loop, which is going to block a CPU at %100 for nothing but the signal handler.